# Connect WAMP to MSSQL 2008 r2: Fatal Error

Tags: php, sql-server, connection, wamp

i have php_mssql.dll and placed it in..

```
> wamp > bin > php > php5.3.0 > ext
```

then i edited the php.ini

i removed the ";" in the extension of php_mssql.dll and php_pdo_mssql.dll..

even though i restarted the services i still have the same error..

in my connection i used this code:

```
<?php

$server = 'YEEN-PC\SQLEXPRESS';

$link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', 'saadmin');

if (!$link) {
    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');
}
?>
```

then i had this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in
>   C:\wamp\www\connect.php on line 5

plss help :(

thanks :)

Comment: you miss the connection string here...

Comment: i edited it :) there i have my code..

Comment: What does phpinfo() say about MSSQL?

Comment: Do you actually have those DLLs on your system where PHP can find them? Check `phpinfo()` output to see if there's any sections about MSSQL support showing up. Uncommenting an extension line does not magically enable support if the necessary files are not present.

Comment: i cant seem to find info about mssql :(

Comment: yes i have those dll's on the php ext folder.. after which i edited the php.ini.. when i check the phpinfo() there are no information about mssql.. does this mean that wamp doesnt support mssql?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to restart the apache service and check your error logs to see if there are some strange entries in there,

Comment: i have restarted the apache service a few times actually i did even restarted all of the services.. i have these in my error logs.. http://i54.tinypic.com/2r1zvpg.png

Comment: Try to open up the dll in notepad++ to see if it is not corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are trying to use PHP 5.3 which doesn't include mssql. As per the [PHP mssql requirements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php):

> This extension is not available anymore on Windows with PHP 5.3 or later.
>
> SqlSrv, an alternative driver for MS SQL is available from Microsoft: » http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx.